# Python property not working in match-case

Tags: python, python-3.10

I am trying to access `Foo` using `Bar` having a `property`.

```
class Foo:
    ONE = "one"
    TWO = "two"
    THREE = "three"

class Bar:

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return Foo



word = "one"

match word:
    case Foo.ONE:         # This is working
        print("GOOD")     

    case Bar().foo.ONE:   # This is not working
        print("BEST")
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I haven't used it yet, and only very briefly skimmed the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) but it seems like the cases can not be arbitrary Python expressions but follow a specific pattern syntax, e.g. "you can use as a pattern the class name followed by an argument list resembling a constructor" but not an _actual_ constructor (or then invoke methods on that instance).

Comment: @Daraan `match` is added in Python 3.10. I get a syntax error from `case Bar().foo.ONE:`

Comment: Uh nice to know, guess it because of the special usage or parentheses in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use evaluations at this place. But you can do what you want with guards:

```
word = "one"

match word:
    
    case str(value) if value == Bar().foo.ONE:   
        print("BEST")
        
    case str(value) if value == Foo.ONE:         
        print("GOOD")
```

The str() is not mandatory, it adds some checking on the type of word.

Comment: Hi Gelineau, Thanks. I tried this, defined `bar = Bar().foo` above `match` and inside `case bar.ONE:`. Now using `guards` I can directly use it instead of creating new variable.